# Can someone please explain this C# function in laymens terms?

Tags: c#, .net

`for (int x = 0; x < 15; x+=2) sum += x + 5;`?

I understand that a += b really means a = a+b. But with that logic I am not sure what this math actually equals. So far i have x is 0, if x is less than 15 then x = a + 2. Not sure what the Sum part means when added to this for statement.

The original question is Which of the following for statements computes the same value for sum as `for (int x = 0; x < 15; x+=2) sum += x + 5;`?

a. `for (int x = 5; x < 20; sum += x-2) x += 2;`

b. `for (int x = 5; x < 20; x+=2) sum += x;`

c. `for (int x = 0; x < 15; sum += x+3) x += 2;`

d. none of the above

e. all of the above

I do not need the answer I just want someone to explain the math to me.

Comment: What do you mean "explain the math"? Like "0 + 5 is 5, 0 + 5 is 5", "0 + 2 is 2, 2 + 5 is 7, 5 + 7 is 12"?

Comment: What happened when you ran it?

Comment: Are you asking what order the statement is evaluated in? As in "is it (sum + x) + 5 or sum + (x + 5)"?

Comment: The math is simple addition. You can work it out yourself with a pencil and paper, if you don't want to be bothered writing and running the code. `sum += 5;` is the same as `sum = sum + 5`.

Comment: I guess I do not understand operaters in c# at all because here is another practice question that does not make sense if you use math logic. Question is Assume integer variables x=10, y=5, z=3, w=2. The value of x + y % w is?  I used examples from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator where they say  of a % b is the value produced by a - (a / b) * b. If that is so then their example below Console.WriteLine(5 % 4);   // output: 1 does not make sense. 5 - (5/4)*4 = 0 not an output of 1?

Comment: This question makes perfect sense from a *math logic* standpoint. It's basic addition with a loop to perform it multiple times. As I said, you can work through it with a pencil and paper. If you don't understand how the `for` loop works, review your course notes or ask your instructor for help, because you've missed something important in your classes.

Comment: Brandon, re `5 - (5 / 4) * 4`, you need to realise that `5 / 4` is *integer* division, giving `1` rather than `1.25`. It's probably easily to think of it *directly* as the remainder operation, giving what remains when you divide five by four with each item being indivisible: `five items divided into four groups gives one item per group, with one item left over`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of *understanding* the code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 15; x+=2) // loop x starting at zero,
                              //   with an increase of two each time,
                              //   continuing if x is less than fifteen.
    sum += x + 5;             // Add x and five to sum.
```

Here's all the *extra* code you need to understand what the sample code is doing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x+=2) {
        sum += x + 5;
        printf("x = %d, sum = %d\n", x, sum); // <<-- This bit specifically.
    }
}
```

Now, granted, that's written in C rather than C#, but the important thing is just realising that all you need to do is *print out* the values after each iteration (with `Console.WriteLine` in C# if memory serves me correctly) and you can see the effect it has.

Then, just do the same for all those other code snippets and see which ones also generate the same result (adding some value to the initial value of `sum`).

---

If you can't run *actual* code for some reason (such as it being a written test with no computers allowed, as you mention in a comment), you need to learn to run code in your *head.* Start with a table:

```
  x | sum
----+-----
    |    0
```

and simply run through the instructions one by one, changing the values as the computer would:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 15; x+=2) sum += x + 5;
```

The first few steps would be:

```
  x |  sum | notes
----+------+------
    |    0 |
  0 |      | Initial setting of x to 0 in loop, <15 so keep going.
    |    5 | Add x and 5 to sum.
  2 |      | Add 2 to x in loop, <15 so keep going.
    |   12 | Add x + 5 to sum.
  4 |      | Add 2 to x in loop, <15 so keep going.
    |   21 | Add x + 5 to sum.
```

And so on.

Comment: I think he'll understand better if you translate it to `C#` ;)

Comment: @Leo, I think they'll *learn* more if they do that bit themselves :-) I *specifically* chose another language so that it wasn't just giving them the answer.

Comment: This is an example of a problem from a practice test. This practice test was paper so how would I be able to solve this problem if I can't run it?

Comment: @Brandon, see the update, you'll need to run the code yourself, using that noggin of yours :-)

Comment: @Brandon You debug it on paper. If you see `for (int x = 0; x < 6; x += 2) sum += x + 5;`, you can step through as the code would when running: Iteration 1. x is 0, sum becomes 0 + 5. Add 2 to x. Iteration 2. x is 2, sum becomes 5 (old value) + 2 + 5. Add 2 to x. Iteration 3. x is 4, sum becomes 12 (old value) + 4 + 5. Add 2 to x. X is >= 6 so stop looping.

Comment: This is a great answer. It not only helps with this question, but teaches a valuable lesson in thinking your way through the code and what it's doing that will benefit the poster (and others who read it) in the future..